# ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService vs ApplicationServies.GetRequiredService with a Singleton Service

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

What's the difference in calling singleton service.

In app.UseMvc();

```
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
    options
        .ServiceProvider
        .GetRequiredService<IYamlIndexer>()
        .IndexContentFiles(Constants.ContentPath);
});
```

Or this:

```
app
    .ApplicationServices
    .GetRequiredService<IYamlIndexer>()
    .IndexContentFiles(Constants.ContentPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Short Answer

For most use cases, there is not a difference between the two. Both properties point to the same `IServiceProvider` instance, and both will get the same instance of a required singleton service. In edge cases, the timing of the calls might be different, but I could not think of an edge case that would cause that to happen. Unless we're doing something unusual, both will run only once, and that will be during application startup.

#### Experiment to Demonstrate

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<SomeSingltonService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var appServices = app.ApplicationServices;
        var appService = appServices.GetRequiredService<SomeSingltonService>();

        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
        Console.WriteLine("Configure");

        app.UseMvc(configureRoutes =>
        {
            var routeServices = routeBuilder.ServiceProvider;
            var routeService = routeServices.GetRequiredService<SomeSingltonService>();

            Console.WriteLine("UseMvc");

            if (appServices == routeServices && appService == routeService)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("They are the same instances.");
            }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
=======================        
Configure                      
UseMvc                         
They are the same instance.    
=======================
```

#### Source Code to Demonstrate

Behind the scenes `UseMvc` passes the `IApplicationBulder` to the `RouteBuilder` constructor. Then the `RouteBuilder` assigns the `IApplicationBulder.ApplicationServices` to its own `IRouteBuilder.ServiceProvider` property.

Code from [MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d09c3c9e2889e9e1c41cdcf3b45f3d724f98fc9f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L136)

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMvc(
    this IApplicationBuilder app,
    Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
{
    // ...

    var routes = new RouteBuilder(app) // ln 136
    {
        DefaultHandler = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<MvcRouteHandler>(),
    };

    configureRoutes(routes);

    // ...
}
```

Code from [RouteBuilder.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/40fb13a02172a0379b40a278391ae1fad716d256/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/RouteBuilder.cs#L36)

```
public RouteBuilder(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IRouter defaultHandler)
{
    // ...

    ServiceProvider = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices; // ln 36

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In (2) `IndexContentFiles` will start immediately, during app startup, while application is not "fully running". This may cause some problems (depending of what IYamlIndexer.IndexContentFiles actually doing). Also, if this is synchronous long-running call - your app will be slow during startup.

In (1) this method will start.. at some time where MVC subsystem will ask for it options. This will occur somewhere after app startup, and again will take some time if it's long-running...

And question you should ask yourself - how Options are configured - singleton or transient (and why you trust this knowlege)? In worst case, your `IndexContentFiles` will be called each time MVC Options are requested and your app will die calling IndexContentFiles on every user request...

May be you need something like [IApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime)?

Comment: What might cause the code inside `UseMvc` to run more than once. I was under the impression that the `configureRoutes` action only runs once and that is during the application startup.

Comment: `UseMvc` runs once, but you provide `Action<>` as param, which can be saved somewhere and run "as needed" and you can't control when and how many times it will be executed.